# Is it possible to Loop through an array of messages and corresponding array of choices in confirm boxes

Tags: loops, confirm

Newbie here, I have googled and couldn't find an answer.

---

I have questions and corresponding choices

```
var questions = ["Would you like A?", "Would you like B?", "Would you like C?"
var choices = [A, B, C]
```

I want to loop both arrays together in one loop or loopish function so the question is asked in a confirm box, and when I confirm or not, that corresponding choice is logged. For example.

"Confirming Question A also confirms Choice A"

As I have it now the confirm boxes loop through the questions, but my selection for choices is showing as undefined in the console log.

```
questions.forEach(function(item, index){
        confirm(item, choices[index]);
        console.log(item, choices[index])
        });
```

I'd like to use the users input towards "if" and "else" statements.

I have this working in chunks of code for A,B and C. But I felt like one loop could knock it out and eliminate a lot of excess code. Maybe wishful thinking?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `confirm` to fill an array with selected answers or null then use `filter` to remove the nulls.

```
var questions = ["Would you like A?", "Would you like B?", "Would you like C?"]
var choices = ["A", "B", "C"]
var sel = []

questions.forEach(function(item, index){
        sel.push(confirm(item, choices[index])?choices[index]:null); // null if not selected
        console.log(item, choices[index]) 
        });
console.log(sel.filter(x => x!=null))  // remove nulls
```

Output (choose A and C)

```
Would you like A?A
Would you like B?B
Would you like C?C
(2) ["A","C"]
```